# How to drop duplicates in python if consecutive values are the same in two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below:

```
A   B   C
1   8   23
2   8   22
3   9   45
4   9   45
5   6   12
6   4   10
7   11  12
```

I want to drop duplicates where keep the first value in the consecutive occurence if the C is also the same.
E.G here occurence '9' is column B is repetitive and their correponding occurences in column 'C' is also repetitive '45'. In this case i want to retain the first occurence.

Expected Output:

```
A   B   C
1   8   23
2   8   22
3   9   45
5   6   12
6   4   10
7   11  12
```

I tried some group by, but didnot know how to drop.

code:

```
df['consecutive'] = (df['B'] != df['B'].shift(1)).cumsum()
test=df.groupby('consecutive',as_index=False).apply(lambda x: (x['B'].head(1),x.shape[0],
                                                       x['C'].iloc[-1] - x['C'].iloc[0]))
```

This group by returns me a series, but i want to drop.

Comment: Only consecutive ones? Or duplicates over the entire dataframe?

Comment: only consecutive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by 2 columns:

```
df['consecutive'] = (df['B'] != df['B'].shift(1)).cumsum()
df = df.drop_duplicates(['consecutive','C'])
print (df)
   A   B   C  consecutive
0  1   8  23            1
1  2   8  22            1
2  3   9  45            2
4  5   6  12            3
5  6   4  10            4
6  7  11  12            5
```

Or chain both conditions with `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
df = df[(df['B'] != df['B'].shift()) | (df['C'] != df['C'].shift())]
print (df)
   A   B   C
0  1   8  23
1  2   8  22
2  3   9  45
4  5   6  12
5  6   4  10
6  7  11  12
```

Answer (score 1):

A oneliner to filter out such records is:

```
df[(df[['B', 'C']].shift() != df[['B', 'C']]).any(axis=1)]
```

Here we thus check if the columns `['B', 'C']` is the same as the shifted rows, if it is not, we retain the values:

```
>>> df[(df[['B', 'C']].shift() != df[['B', 'C']]).any(axis=1)]
   A   B   C
0  1   8  23
1  2   8  22
2  3   9  45
4  5   6  12
5  6   4  10
6  7  11  12
```

This is quite scalable, since we can define a function that will easily operate on an arbitrary number of values:

```
def drop_consecutive_duplicates(df, *colnames):
    dff = df[list(colnames)]
    return df[(dff.shift() != dff).any(axis=1)]
```

So you can then filter with:

```
drop_consecutive_duplicates(df, 'B', 'C')
```

Answer (score 1):

the easy way to check the difference between row of B and C then drop value if difference is 0 (duplicate values), the code is

```
 df[ ~((df.B.diff()==0) & (df.C.diff()==0)) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html), [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) over `axis=1`:

*Note: this method only works for numeric columns*

```
m = df[['B', 'C']].diff().ne(0).any(axis=1)
print(df[m])
```

**Output**

```
   A   B   C
0  1   8  23
1  2   8  22
2  3   9  45
4  5   6  12
5  6   4  10
6  7  11  12
```

---

**Details**

```
df[['B', 'C']].diff()

     B     C
0  NaN   NaN
1  0.0  -1.0
2  1.0  23.0
3  0.0   0.0
4 -3.0 -33.0
5 -2.0  -2.0
6  7.0   2.0
```

Then we check if `any` of the values in a row are not equal (`ne`) to `0`:

```
df[['B', 'C']].diff().ne(0).any(axis=1)

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute a series of the rows to drop, and then drop them:

```
to_drop = (df['B'] == df['B'].shift())&(df['C']==df['C'].shift())
df = df[~to_drop]
```

It gives as expected:

```
   A   B   C
0  1   8  23
1  2   8  22
2  3   9  45
4  5   6  12
5  6   4  10
6  7  11  12
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['B', 'C'])
```

**Result**

```
   A   B   C
0  1   8  23
1  2   8  22
2  3   9  45
4  5   6  12
5  6   4  10
6  7  11  12
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, given the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [8, 8, 9, 9, 6, 4, 11], 'C': [22, 23, 45, 45, 12, 10, 12],})
```

This one-line code solved your problem using the [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['B', 'C'])
```

It gives as expected results:

```
    B   C
0   8  22
1   8  23
2   9  45
4   6  12
5   4  10
6  11  12
```